# Immediate relative visa to the US about to expire

Tags: visas, usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, covid-19

I applied for my mother to be able to migrate and reside in the United States, after months of following the appropriate procedures and waiting to hear a response from USCIS, and later the NVC her application was approved.

My mother lives in Lima, Peru, but due to this pandemic, she was not to fly into the United States mainly because the Peruvian President did a national lockdown and International flights were all canceled.

My question is as follows: Her passport was stamped with a visa with an expiration of 6 months from the day she was interviewed and was granted permission to travel to the United States. Due to the coronavirus and this restriction from the Peruvian president, her visa will expire before Peru is able to reopen its border allowing for international flights.

Do any of you know if they are making any extensions for this type of scenario or if they are requiring to submit any type of extensions?